# set the timezone to UTC which is already in UTC

Tags: java, postgresql, date, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have application in which I have set the timezone to UTC as follows:

```
// set default time zone to UTC
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

This is fine for all date fields that we are storing in database as UTC.
But one date is already coming in UTC so above timezone will again set it in UTC.

How to avoid setting it again in UTC?

Some code-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        DatatypeFactory datatypeFactory  = DatatypeFactory.
         newInstance();
        // set default time zone to UTC
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        // coming from external program in UTC but assigned it here for reference
        long someTimeToBeInUTC = 1528371000000L;
        GregorianCalendar start = new GregorianCalendar();
        start.setTimeInMillis(someTimeToBeInUTC);
        XMLGregorianCalendar startXmlCalendar  = 
        datatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(start);
        System.out.println(startXmlCalendar.
        toGregorianCalendar().getTime());

    }
```

Think like I have a time instant `someTimeToBeInUTC` irrespective of a timezone and then because of the line `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC))` it sets it in UTC.

Then in hibernate I have the property in hbm.xml of the table where I am storing this value-

```
<property name="startTime" type="timestamp">
            <column name="start_time" length="29" />
        </property>
```

The type of startTime is timestamp without timezone in postgres.
So when we save then it again converts it in UTC.

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem? The output seems fine.

Comment: The problem is `someTimeToBeInUTC` is already in UTC coming from external program. So the line `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));` sets it again in UTC.

Comment: What do you mean "sets it again"? Is your problem that it's "inefficient"? Because it isn't. And anyway, a timestamp is usually an instant in time irrespective of a timezone.

Comment: @Michael- the instant is irrespective of timezone but then when I save it then it is not saved as it is. It is getting saved with the difference of my local timezone i.e. it is again applying my local timezone difference and then getting saved. Please check my updated question.

Comment: If I remove the line `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC))` then it will correctly save the time in UTC but then other date fields which are already coming without UTC from external program will get saved with my timezone (not in UTC).

Comment: Wild guess about what your problem really is: you normally receive time values in local time and have a conversion to UTC implemented somewhere (obviously not in the code you are showing), but you get UTC time values from some source now and therefore your conversion mishandles these UTC time values?!?

Comment: Please take a step back. Tell us **the result you are getting** and **the result you are expecting** with respect to the example you have given us.

Comment: "But one date is already coming in UTC so above timezone will again set it in UTC."

How do you know it is already in UTC? It's a datetime object that contains timezone? If yes, the question is irrelevant, the database should recognize the timezone in the object.
If you get a timestamp without a timezone declaration but you know this source provides UTC in every single time, then as soon as the timestamp enters to your app, convert it to a datetime object with zone declaration -> problem gone.

Comment: @Michael- The current time is 6:41 PM here. The UI takes the time from user as input in UTC - `1:12 PM UTC`. So I want to save it in postgres as `1:12 PM` without any further conversion to UTC (because it is already in UTC). But I am getting it further converted in UTC as I see in database. So its 2 times conversion in UTC.

Comment: What you are getting from the user, is that in format `1528371000000L` or in format `1:12 PM UTC` or in some third format? And how would it look in the cases where it is not in UTC and thus needs conversion? (Seems you are at offset +05:30 from UTC.)

Comment: @OleV.V.- You are absolutely correct. I am getting in format `1528371000000L`. Then I am using `XMLGregorianCalendar` to set it. I am at offset +05:30 from UTC.  The other dates are triggers at database level like created_ts and modified_ts for that row in table.

Comment: A timestamp like `1528371000000L` is milliseconds since the epoch of Jan 1, 1970 at 00:00:00 UTC. So provided that your values are correct, they are independent of time zone, and you don’t have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Time in milliseconds has nothing about time zone.

Time in milliseconds is exact point in time regardless where you use it in Calendar, Date or Timestamp objects.

Please read Java documentation carefully. It represents always milliseconds passed  from epoch (1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC).

Time Zone has effect only when other representation used from those objects. e.g. from toString() methods, get fields  from Calendar etc.)

**UPDATE**
Let say you have time in milleseconds as `1528371250000L`...

then you can have two Calendars (they are TimeZone aware) one in UTC one, in Eastern

see the full code example to illustrate what's going on when the same time in millisecond set in both of them:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    Calendar utcCalendar = Calendar
            .getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    utcCalendar.setTimeInMillis(1528371250000L);

    System.out.println("UTC Calendar: \t\t" + (utcCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) +1)
            + "/" + utcCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/"
            + utcCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " "
            + utcCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
            + utcCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
            + utcCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + " " + utcCalendar.getTimeZone().getID());

    Calendar eastCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone
            .getTimeZone("EST"));

    eastCalendar.setTimeInMillis(1528371250000L);

    System.out.println("Eastern Calendar: \t"
            + (eastCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "/"
            + eastCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/"
            + eastCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " "
            + eastCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
            + eastCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
            + eastCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + " " + eastCalendar.getTimeZone().getID());

    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlUtcCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar((GregorianCalendar) utcCalendar);

    System.out.println("XML UTC Calendar: \t" + xmlUtcCalendar.toString());

    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlEastCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar((GregorianCalendar) eastCalendar);

    System.out.println("XML Eastern Calendar: \t" + xmlEastCalendar.toString());

}
```

Output:

```
 UTC Calendar:          6/7/2018 11:34:10 UTC
 Eastern Calendar:      6/7/2018 6:34:10 EST
 XML UTC Calendar:      2018-06-07T11:34:10.000Z
 XML Eastern Calendar:  2018-06-07T06:34:10.000-05:00
```

Comment: I understand that part that time in milliseconds is the instant since 1970. However, my problem is my code is not able to handle the time which is already in UTC converted to milliseconds and stored again in UTC.

Comment: Again, time in milliseconds cannot be converted to any time zone.  See updated example in my answer. All 4 calendars have same time in millisecond values.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You seem to be working much too hard.

You are using the wrong classes. Use modern *java.time* classes instead.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(
    … , 
    Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_528_371_000_000L ) 
)
```

You are using the wrong [data type in your database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html). The `TIMEZONE WITHOUT TIME ZONE` type *cannot* be used to store a specific moment.

## Avoid setting default time zone

> TimeZone.setDefault

This call immediately affects all code in all threads of all apps within the JVM! So make this call only in the most desperate of circumstances.

Instead, pass the desired/expected time zone as an optional [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) argument to many of the *java.time* methods.

The default time zone of your host OS and your JVM should both be irrelevant to your code. Specify explicitly your desired/expected time zone as a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) (or [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)) object.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes.

The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are terrible. This includes the `GregorianCalendar` class seen in your code. Instead, use their replacement, the modern *java.time* classes.

Specifically, `GregorianCalendar` is replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

## `Instant`

The `Instant` class in *java.time* is the basic building block. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Apparently you have a count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of [first moment of 1970 UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Simply parse that number as a `Instant` object by calling [`ofEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli(long)).

```
long input = 1_528_371_000_000L ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( input ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-06-07T11:30:00Z

### Time zones

You may want to present the `Instant` to the user in a particular time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;  // Or Europe/Paris, Africa/Tunis, etc.
```

## Database

I do not know what you are doing with `XMLGregorianCalendar`. And I cannot address Hibernate as I am not a user, though I know [Hibernate supports *java.time* types](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844).

But if you trying to record and retrieve a moment with Postgres, you are working much too hard.

Storing a moment in UTC into a column of type `TIMESTAMP WTH TIME ZONE` (*not* `WITHOUT`! — see below).

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl ( event ) VALUES ( ? ) ;" ;       // Writing a moment into a column of type `TIMESTAMP WTH TIME ZONE`.
…
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_528_371_000_000L ) ;  // Representing a moment in UTC.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , instant ) ;                  // As of JDBC 4.2 and later, we can directly exchange java.time objects with our database.
```

Retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

Be aware that the SQL standard barely touches on the topic of date-time. Different databases behave *very* differently from one another in their handling of date-time.

The way Postgres works is that `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is something of a misnomer. The time zone is *not* stored as part of the timestamp. Any supplied time zone of offset-from-UTC information submitted with input is used to adjust into UTC. The UTC value is written to the database. The zone/offset is then discarded/forgotten. If remembering the original zone/offset of the input is important to you, you must store it separately in another column.

When retrieving a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value from Postgres, you are *always* getting a value in UTC. This may not be apparent to you if your middleware tool connecting you (your app) with the database injects its own opinion as to a desirable time zone for presentation.

Avoiding this time zone injection confusion is easy with Java: **Pass `Instant` objects, and retrieve `Instant` objects.** An `Instant` is always in UTC. So calling `ResultSet::getObject( … , Instant.class)` will always represent faithfully the database’s `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value.

One tricky point is resolution of the fractional second. The *java.time* classes use nanoseconds resolution while Postgres uses microseconds. So you may want to truncate your `Instant` explicitly in your code to acknowledge this fact. Your JDBC driver will truncate for you, but I dislike such behind-the-scenes manipulation of data.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLISECONDS ) ;  // Lop off any nanoseconds to match Postgres storing microseconds.
```

### Wrong data type in your column

> The type of startTime is timestamp without timezone in postgres.

The `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` is the *wrong* data type to store a moment. This type lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it cannot represent a specific moment. It represents the set of *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of all time zones).

Instead, you should be using the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type to store a a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

> So when we save then it again converts it in UTC.

Nope, not at all. Just the opposite. Any included time zone or offset-from-UTC information is ignored. The date and time-of-day are take as-is, with no accounting for time zone, no adjusting to UTC.

The SQL-standard type `TIMEZONE WITHOUT TIME ZONE` is equivalent to the *java.time* type `LocalDateTime`.

You should use these zone-less types only in these three situations:

- The **zone or offset is unknown**.
  This is bad. This is faulty data. Analogous to having a price/cost without knowing the currency. You should be rejecting such data, not storing it.
- The **intention is “everywhere”**, as in, every time zone.
  Example, a corporate policy that states “All our factories will break for lunch at 12:30" means the factory in Delhi will break hours before the factory in Düsseldorf which breaks hours before the factory in Detroit.
- A specific moment in the future is intended, but we are **afraid of politicians redefining the time zone**.
  Governments change the rules of their time zones with surprising frequency and with surprisingly [little warning](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-34631326) or even [no warning at all](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-44010705). So if you want to book an appointment at 3 PM on a certain date, and you really mean 3 PM regardless of any crazy decision a government might make in the interim, then store a `LocalDateTime`. To print a report or display a calendar, dynamically apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to generate a specific moment (`ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`). This must be done on-the-fly rather than storing the value.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).